# Defining global variable in - jquery.validate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying get the value of global variable in jquery validation plugin.

```
var typedWords = 1;
jQuery.validator.addMethod("wordCount",
       function(value, element, params) {
                 typedWords = jQuery.trim(value).split(' ').length;
                 console.log(typedWords);
                 if (typedWords >= params[0] && typedWords <= params[1]) {
                     return true;
                  }
               },
               jQuery.format("Only {0} to {1} words allowed. You have entered " + typedWords + " words.")
            );
```

however the value of typedWords in `jQuery.format("Only {0} to {1} words allowed. You have entered " + typedWords + " words.")` is always `undifined`.

How am i suppose to get the value of `typedWords = jQuery.trim(value).split(' ').length;` ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference, but why are you using a global variable instead of a local variable?

Comment: It looks like it should work. Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Barmar yes.. i felt like it should work too.. but its not :(..

Comment: Please make a _complete_ concise example to demonstrate the problem.  This means you'll need to show us the relevant HTML and your call to the `.validate()` method with options.

Comment: @Barmar, see custom message which contains the global variable and `jQuery.format` has been deprecated.

Comment: I mistakenly thought he was talking about `console.log(typedWords)`. The problem with the call to `jQuery.format` is that it's using the variable when the method is defined, not when it's run.

Comment: @Barmar, that wasn't the root issue.  He was getting `undefined` because `jQuery.format()` is deprecated.  Once I changed it to `jQuery.validator.format()` it started working partially.  See answer.

Comment: Why would he get an incorrect value because the function is deprecated? Deprecated functions still work, it's just a warning that the function may go away in a future version.

Comment: @Barmer, he wasn't getting an incorrect/correct value.  Warning or not, the custom rule/method was doing nothing at all.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/JRgN7/4/ ~ And removing the variable from the message fixes nothing:  http://jsfiddle.net/JRgN7/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the console errors, it's telling me that `$.format` from `jquery.validate.js` has been deprecated.  So simply change `$.format` into `$.validator.format`, or in your case...

```
jQuery.validator.format("Only {0} to {1} words allowed. You have entered " + typedWords + " words.")
```

(*Wrapping the custom message within `$.validator.format()` is no longer needed at all, as leaving it out entirely make no difference.*)

It works now, except the `typedWords` variable will never be updated beyond the `1` you've defined globally.  That's because once you've initialized the custom method, the only pieces of the custom message that can dynamically change are the parameters at `{0}` and `{1}`.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JRgN7/**

However, if you assign `typedWords` to another parameter called `params[2]`, you can use `{2}` within the message and it correctly updates itself.

```
var typedWords = 1;
jQuery.validator.addMethod("wordCount", function (value, element, params) {
    typedWords = jQuery.trim(value).split(' ').length;
    params[2] = typedWords;
    console.log(typedWords);
    if (typedWords >= params[0] && typedWords <= params[1]) {
        return true;
    }
},
jQuery.validator.format("Only {0} to {1} words allowed. You have entered {2} words."));
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JRgN7/1/**

Now we can just use `params[2]` and eliminate the global `typedWords` variable entirely.  Also, it's not necessary to put the custom message inside `jQuery.validator.format()` anymore.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("wordCount", function (value, element, params) {
    params[2] = jQuery.trim(value).split(' ').length;
    if (params[2] >= params[0] && params[2] <= params[1]) {
        return true;
    }
},
"Only {0} to {1} words allowed. You have entered {2} words.");
```

**FINAL Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/JRgN7/3/**